# Simplifying $\csc^{-1}(\sec 2)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How do I simplify $\csc^{-1}(\sec 2)$?
The answer in the book is $\frac\pi2 - 2$.

Comment: can you write $\sec$ in terms of $\csc?$

Comment: Hint: Think co-function.

Answer (score 9):

We have that
$$\cos x = \sin\left(\frac\pi2 - x\right)$$

Therefore
$$\sec 2 = \frac1{\cos 2} = \frac1{\sin\left(\frac\pi2 - 2\right)} = \csc\left(\frac\pi2 - 2\right)$$

Finally
$$\csc^{-1}(\sec 2) = \csc^{-1}\left(\csc\left(\frac\pi2 - 2\right)\right) = \frac\pi2 - 2.$$

Comment: Thank you very much.You save my day

Comment: @Dinie: Glad to be of help! You could accept the answer by clicking on the tick below the votes buttons.